# Printing HTML5 Canvas in IE6/7

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, excanvas

I know IE6/7 does not natively support canvas and so I'm using excanvas.js for IE browsers. I have a script which draws two images onto a canvas tag. 
Eg.

```
var canvas = $('.map_container')[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.drawImage(images.national,getPositionOrScale(0),getPositionOrScale(0),getPositionOrScale(images.national.width),getPositionOrScale(images.national.height));
```

Now I call context.drawImage on two different images and both images are drawn but when I'm in IE6/7 and I go to print preview or print it. It only prints the last img which was drawn.

Any ideas why it cant print the full canvas as is?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? :(

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to find an answer. As soon as you mention IE6/7 people automatically say "why dont you upgrade or get a proper browser"

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that they get layered on top of each other. I'm sure this is ancient history for you, but if you put one of the two in a div with a height set to the size of the canvas, you should be able to see both.